# How can I specify that Doctrine must use a mysqli-connection

Tags: php, doctrine, mysqli

while executing a long script that uses Doctrine to access the db, I get an error 2006 server has gone away.

I've already solved this problem on a website that doens't use Doctrine. The solution there was to use mysqli instead of the normal mysql driver.

How can i tell Doctrine to use a mysqli-driver in order to avoid 2006-errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this, because Doctrine uses [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) rather than the older mysqli or mysql extensions.

Comment: @murze: does it happen when you run specific queries or does it just fail after a long time? I have had it in the past where the server's max_allowed_packet mysql setting is too low. But that wouldn't explain why it works in mysqli

Comment: it happens when I try to execute a doctrine command after an api-call to mailchimp. The answer of the api-call takes about 50 seconds.

Comment: @murze: You could try changing wait_timeout on your mysql server, e.g. run the sql: `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=60` . Also is your PHP version up to date? i did read about some issues like this with PDO/MySQL and PHP version 5.1

Comment: My php version 5.2.12. Unfortunately I'm on shared hosting and can't change any of the globel mysql-parameters.

Comment: Doctrine can be told to use Mysqli by specifying the `mysqli` driver. See [the documentation for the Mysqli driver's options](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#mysqli)

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine can be told to use Mysqli by specifying the `mysqli` driver. See [the documentation for the Mysqli driver's options](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#mysqli)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$masterConn->getDbh()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
```

If prepared statements are used, add this,

```
$masterConn->getDbh()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Comment: Hi, i tried 
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh);
$conn->getDbh()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
$conn->getDbh()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

but still got the 2006 server has gone away error :-(